# Date selector popup in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

I'd like to setup an entire column, so that it will only contain dates, and I won't have to manully enter the date string. Instead, I'd like a click on the cell to pop up a calender selector.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

[Pop up calendar for excel](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut07.htm) (download at bottom)

OR

**EDIT:**

> The link below was the solution that
>   worked for the asker of the question.

[Other popup calendar](http://www.wincalendar.com/excel-pop-up-calendar.html)

OR

[Yet another pop calendar](http://www.office-kit.com/excel_calendar/index.htm)

Comment: Isn't there something built in?

Comment: The calendar control is built-in, you just need to apply a little bit of code to get the results you are looking for, however if you are looking for an add-on hidden in the menu, it does not exist.

Comment: Yes, just edit it to indicate what actually worked for me (actually I was asking it for a friend, and he said the first link wasn't good ... I can't really tell you what was wrong with it).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help or not ...

You do not always have to enter the entire date in Excel

If you type "**10/12**" excel will assume **10/12/2009**

You can format the cell to display the date in a wide range of formats. If you format the cell to show say the whole date, for example format **dddd mmmm/dd/yyyy**
then excel will show **Monday October/12/2009**

if you type **1/2/3** in the cell then excel will show **Thursday January/02/2003**

Personally, I find this style of date entry a lot easier that clicking through pop-up calendars.